# How can Go Documentation be generated from any folder?

Tags: go

I have a package with files called `test` which is in the folder `~/my_packages/test`.

My GoPath is set to `~/go`, i.e

```
$ echo $GOPATH
~/go
```

What arguments need to be passed to `godoc` in to view the documentation of files for the `test` package?

I have tried:

- `godoc -goroot=~/my_packages test`

  - Result: `cannot find package "." in: /src/test`
- `godoc -goroot=~/my_packages ./test`

  - Result: `cannot find package "." in: /target`
- `export GOPATH=$GOPATH:~/my_packages; godoc test`

  - Result: `cannot find package "." in: /src/test`

I can start the godoc HTTP server and see the folder, but only the code is visible. The expected package documentation is not available.

```
godoc -http=:6060 -goroot=/full/path/to/my_packages
```

What `godoc` command can be run to generate documentation for packages in folders in any directory?

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: I don't think you can do that, godoc expects the packages to be under a src/ directory. If you placed your `test` package in `~/my_packages/src/` , so there would be a `~/my_packages/src/test` directory, you could run `GOROOT=~/my_packages godoc test` though.

Comment: @nos Good enough, thank you!